# header('location:exaxmple.php') not working in pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am wondering why this is happening only in my code.

In my code, the query executes successfully, but it doesn't redirect.

Working code (`pdo`):

```
<?php

  $fname=$_POST['fname'];
  $lname=$_POST['lname'];
  $sql="INSERT INTO contacts(first_name,last_name)";
  $query = $db->prepare($sql);
  $success=$query->execute(array(':fname'=>$fname,':lname'=>$lname,);
  if($success)
       {
           header('location:contacts.php');

       }
       else
       {
           echo "Error";

       }
?>
```

It is working on `localhost` but not on the server. Is this an issue related to my code?

Comment: if i am using `if($success) { echo "s";}` it will echo and inserts. but problem only with header location

Comment: check your server support it

Comment: @saleemnfs : it supports,

Comment: Is this all the php code? You won't be able to send a header if the headers already have been send. Make sure nothing is output before header or use buffering (buffering options in your php.ini on the server might be different).

Comment: yes all php code..and no headers already sent

Comment: Debug more! "Isn't working" isn't granular enough to be able to say anything. Is it entering the `if ($success)` condition or not? Is it *trying* to output the header or not? Have you checked your error logs for possible error messages?

Comment: @condition0 This can't be `all` the PHP code because `$db` is not defined anywhere

Comment: $db i added in connect page and included that page

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/contacts.php');
```

The reason is you should use **Absolute URL** when working on server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks strange...

because code: `header('location:contacts.php');` should works (here everything correct),

i suppose that you should receive: `echo "Error";`
because as i see, you have error at your sql.

Instead:

```
  $sql="INSERT INTO contacts(first_name,last_name)";
```

you should write:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO contacts SET first_name = :fname, last_name = :lname";
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this, it should work for you.

HTML: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://yoursite.com /contacts.php">`

JavaScript #1: `<script>window.location = "http://yoursite.com/contacts.php";</script>`

JavaScript #2: `<script>window.navigate("http://yoursite.com/contacts.php");</script>`

Comment: what you mean? where i put this